# php how to get htmlcontent instead textcontent

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

In `var2`, I want HTML content, as there are some `br` so they are not getting included and I want them to get included.

```
<?php
$url = "http://sms.hindijokes.co";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
@$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".$html."
</body>      </html>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query1 = "//h2[@class='entry-title']/a";
$query2 = "//div[@class='entry-content'][1]/p";
$entries1 = $xpath->query($query1);
$entries2 = $xpath->query($query2);
$var1 = $entries1->item(0)->textContent;
$var2 = $entries2->item(0)->textContent;
echo "$var1"; 
echo "<br>";
$f = $entries2->length;
for($i = 0; $i < $f; $i++){
    echo $entries2->item($i)->textContent."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: temporary solution you can try using 'nl2br($entries1->item(0)->textContent)'

Comment: Try this, `$var2 = $entries2->item(0)->ownerDocument->saveHTML($entries2->item(0));`

Comment: Not working this way

Comment: @DaveChen Is their any other way?

Comment: The new line characters are there, but if you are rendering your output as HTML then they will not be displayed as a new line break - as bugscoder suggested, you can use nl2br. Run [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gh06-8vzn) to see that some of the strings do have a new line character.